# ¿Cómo obtener determinados registros por una columna?

Tags: mysql

estaba creando esta pequeña tabla en MySQL para ver se había forma de resolver esta consulta.

```
   CREATE TABLE prueba
(
CATEGORIA               VARCHAR(5),
SUBCATEGORIA        VARCHAR(5),
MONTO                       DECIMAL(5,2)
);

SELECT * FROM prueba;

INSERT INTO prueba VALUES
("A", "A1", 55.00),
("A", "A2", 35.00),
("A", "A3", 26.00),
("A", "A4", 36.00),
("B", "B1", 18.00),
("B", "B2", 29.00),
("B", "B3", 36.00),
("C", "C1", 11.00),
("C", "C2", 16.00),
("C", "C3", 18.00),
("C", "C4", 20.00),
("C", "C5", 28.00);
```

Donde el resultado es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con una query filtrar por mi primera columna de tal forma en la que obtenga solo 2 registros por cada CATEGORIA y los de menor monto. Tratando de obtener el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero en el grupo de las A no debería recibir el 26 en lugar del 35? lo digo por que se supone que buscas los de menor monto

Comment: Error mío, pero sí, busco las de menor monto y solo 2 o bueno los que se decida en el momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero se puede particionar el resultset por la columna `categoria` y ordenarlo por monto de forma ascendente y aplicar la función `ROW_NUMBER()` para darle un número a la fila, quedando la consulta así:

```
SELECT *, 
       Row_number() -- agrega el número de la fila
         OVER ( 
           partition BY categoria  -- se crea la partición por categoria
           -- y se ordena por monto asc
           ORDER BY monto ASC ) orden 
FROM   prueba
```

Luego se puede usar esa consulta como sub consulta para filtrar las filas que tengan orden <= 2 ( las primeras dos de cada categoría ), quedando así:

```
SELECT categoria, 
       subcategoria, 
       monto 
FROM  (SELECT *, 
              Row_number() 
                OVER ( 
                  partition BY categoria 
                  ORDER BY monto ASC ) orden 
       FROM   prueba) tabla_ordenada 
WHERE  orden <= 2
```

**NOTA:** Esa consulta funciona en MySQL 8.0 en adelante.

Comment: Creo que sería conveniente indiques a partir de que versión de MySQL están disponibles las window functions como la que usas (*lo digo por si el OP usa una que no lo soporte*)

Comment: Menos mal tengo una versión superior, y sí, esta solución funcionó perfectamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema recurrente que gracias a las [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) se puede realizar mas directamente. Para versiones previas de mysql se puede realizar usando @variables. La siguiente consulta entrega el valor para versiones anteriores de MySQL

```
SELECT categoria, 
       subcategoria, 
       monto 
FROM (
  SELECT @pos:=if(@cat!=categoria,1,@pos+1) orden,@cat:=categoria as categoria, 
         subcategoria, 
         monto 
  FROM prueba , (SELECT @pos:=0, @cat:='') tmp
  ORDER BY categoria,monto
 ) t
WHERE orden<=2
```

En el ejemplo las variables se inicializan en `(SELECT @pos:=0, @cat:='') tmp` y `@pos` se vuelve a 1 al cambiar de categoria `@cat`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4623cc/7/0